# Loading Images into a tableview cell, according to object loaded from NSUserDefaults

Tags: image, uitableview, xcode4.5, nsuserdefaults

I have a tableview populated by objects loaded from NSUserDefaults.

Specifically - when a user presses a button in one view controller, a string is loaded into NSUserDefaults, which is then loaded into an array, which finally populates a table view.

I am wondering how I can load an image in each tableview cell, dependent on what string is loaded from NSUserDefaults?

I don't want to save images IN NSUserDefaults, as I am aware this is not a good idea.

What can I do?

Thank you for your time (and helping a novice out)!

---

Update 19FEB13

The Strings I am loading into NSUserDefaults are the names of objects, for example "ARCX".

At the moment I have tried a variety of pieces of code, but I am at the point where I seem to have a misunderstanding/lack of knowledge (or both).

```
UITableViewCell *XCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:IndexPath];
NSString *content = Xcell.textLabel.text;

if ([content isEqualToString:@"ARCX"]) [UIImage *Image = [UIImage imageNamed @"ARCX.png"]];
```

Obviously I'm getting errors from this code.

I hope you can help!

---

Update 20FEB13

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     NSString *string = [myOBJArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"XCell";
     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
     if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        UIView *cellbackground = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        cellbackground.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MSP cell bg MK2.png"]];
        cell. backgroundView = cellbackground;

}

cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor ];
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:24.0];
cell.textLabel.text = string;


 UITableViewCell *XCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
 NSString *content = XCell.textLabel.text;

 if ([content isEqualToString:@"ARCX"]) [UIImage *Image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"ARCX.png" ]];


cell.imageView.image = Image;

     return cell;
```

}

I did have the code I initially posted in the CellForRowAtIndexPath, but I know I am missing something in the implementation (obviously as it doesn't work!).

Thanks for your time!

---

Update 19Feb13

I This is my current CellForRowAtIndexPath. No errors, but yet no images in my cells. What am I missing?

Have I got to add an image view? I am currently using a 'basic' cell, not a custom one.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *string = [myObjArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MSCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    UIView *cellbackground = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    cellbackground.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MSP cell bg MK2.png"]];
    cell. backgroundView = cellbackground;
}

cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor ];
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:24.0];
cell.textLabel.text = string;

if ([string isEqualToString:@"ARCX"])

cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"ARCX.png"];

else if ([string isEqualToString:@"WPX"])

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"WPX.png"];


 return cell;
```

}

Thanks for your time!

Comment: What was the string you loading to NSUserDefaults. Is it a remote url? Please post some sample code you tried.

Comment: You should add your `UIImage` in tableview's `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method. Please post the code in that method.

Comment: I have posted the Code for CellForRowAtIndex, I hope you can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UITableViewCell *XCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString *content = XCell.textLabel.text;
```

Please remove this piece of code, as it will call cellForRowAtIndexPath again and again.
You already have the image name as string

```
NSString *string = [myOBJArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

So change the code like below.

```
if ([string isEqualToString:@"ARCX"]) 
        UIImage *Image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"ARCX.png"];
cell.imageView.image = Image;
```

Comment: Dear, HRM - your code seemed pretty close, but threw up two errors when I implemented it. I have changed it slightly into what you can see in my most recent edit. ALthough it is now error free, it still does not work! Can you help?

Comment: Please check 2 things: 1)Add `NSLog` in your `if` and `else if` condition and make sure `cell.imageView` is set.2)Just try to add a `UIImageView` in your view with the image names you are giving and verify whether the images are correcly displaying.

Comment: Dear HRM, I checked the cell.imageView and that was fine, but in doing so my Mac crashed. On restart I cleaned the project and now it works! How strange, thanks for all your help!